# react native universal links for ios

Tags: react-native-ios, ios-universal-links

I am new to React Native, I developed a small app in react native and am trying to deeplink to my website. I know this question is so silly but I am not able to crack this for days.

Here is my problem statement:

In info.plist if I add my scheme (say myapp), then if I open Safari browser and hit myapp:// it prompts to open in MyApp.
But I need to link it to my website(say www.mywebsite.in) so adding a scheme https, then if I hit it in browser it doesn't and instead it opens my website.

Not able to understand why it doesn't open. Please suggest.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I believe you're looking to do is called "universal linking", and it's slightly more complex than deep linking. You'll need to add an apple-app-site-association file on the server that hosts the associated site ([instructions here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/enabling_universal_links)).

You'll also have to add the appropriate entitlements for universal linking. If you're using Xcode, you can add e.g. `applinks:www.mywebsite.in` under `Capabilities -> Associated Domains`. Or in your entitlements file, you can add something like the following:

```
<key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
<array>   
    ...
    <string>applinks:www.mywebsite.in</string>
    ...
</array>
```

Everything else should be pretty similar to the setup for deep links, but be sure you set up the `apple-app-site-association` file correctly (either at the root or in `.well-known/` on your web server, and no redirects).